# "All Jobs" showing only 12 jobs for users from Japan

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

There's currently only a small number of jobs appearing on the site.

All jobs: http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs?f=t shows 12 jobs.

> [image]

Python jobs: http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/tag/python shows 3 jobs.

C# jobs: http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/tag/c%23 shows 1 job.

Further details:

- I'm in Japan.
- If I do a location search: http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs?location=london&range=20&distanceUnits=Miles I get 0 jobs. "0 jobs near London, UK".
- I've tried logged in vs not, and ubuntu desktop vs mac laptop. I get the same results in all 4 combinations.
- I can't see any commonality between the 12 jobs that appear: they range from posts from 5 weeks ago to 4 hours ago, there's no common tag, there's no common location, and they're alphabetically diverse.

Comment: Unable to replicate. I see 2500, 641, and 488, respectively.

Comment: Is it possible that the number of jobs is limited to the geography in which you are located? In Australia, I see 930, 244, and 147 respectively

Comment: @PolyGeo I'm in Japan, but if I go to: http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs?location=london&range=20&distanceUnits=Miles I get 0 jobs. "0 jobs near London, UK".

Comment: Maybe asia is served by a different set of servers explaining the lack of reproducibility from other countries?

Comment: Reproduced using  web proxy, sending false headers as if I'm from Japan. The amount of jobs is indeed based on your location, which is super weird since the 12 jobs shown to user from Japan are not even in Japan.

Comment: Is that an artefact of the location the jobs were entered?

Comment: I see 1661 jobs.

Comment: @Anonymous Possible bug. We implemented a new search algo Friday, Stuff is definitely broken but not sure if this applies. Looking into it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whoops, sorry about that. It should be fixed now. There was a bug in the new search backend preventing some jobs (a lot in this case) from showing up.

Comment: Is this still location-sensitive though, i.e. different results based on the user's IP address? If so, it's a bad idea IMO. Job lists should be job lists, if user want to filter, there are other ways, more transparent.

Comment: @ShadowWizard when an employer posts a listing they're asked what advertising region they want to target (see http://imgur.com/h0C2Zoo). Users in certain regions only see listings for that region and listings marked as "Worldwide".

Comment: @Dean thanks, I'm going to start feature request asking to show the relevant region(s) then, so users won't wonder why each is seeing different results (e.g. 902 jobs in the Middle East area)

Comment: @Dean but the Job location has nothing to do with th IP address. I could be in country A searching for a Job on country B. I could be on vacations, or planning to move in. It makes no sense at all.