# Show the targeted region when viewing Job Listings

Tags: feature-request, jobs

Following [this bug report](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251829/all-jobs-showing-only-12-jobs-for-users-from-japan), I learned that the [Job Listings results](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs?f=t) are based on the user location.

After the bug fix, this is what I see when browsing as usual: (Israel)

> [image]

Users from Japan see this, in exact same web address: (used proxy to see it)

> [image]

And users in Netherlands see this:

> [image]

Dean revealed [in a comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251829/all-jobs-showing-only-12-jobs-for-users-from-japan#comment822786_251912) how this works, internally:

> [image]

This might cause confusion, keep in mind that many people, especially in the IT world, use VPN/Proxy servers on regular basis e.g. someone living in Europe having IP address of USA hence will see "wrong" results.

So my request is simply to display the relevant region, e.g.:

> [image]