# Why Careers filter Job searches by client IP?

Tags: discussion, status-bydesign, jobs, search

I am working from Argentina for a company in Amsterdam. We want to hire a new Dev so we put an advise on Careers.

When I search for jobs in Amsterdam from Argentina the listing from our company is not there!

I searched using a proxy, so the request looks like it was made from Amsterdam, and not only our listing appeared, a lot more of results did too.

I don't think this is a good thing. What if a person from Amsterdam is on vacation somewhere else looking for Job. Or if someone is planning to move to some other country?

- Why is this a search criteria?
- Isn't the location filter enough?

I've even tried using the company name as keyword and nothing happened!

EDIT: This is not a duplicate of ["All Jobs" showing only 12 jobs for users from Japan](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251829/all-jobs-showing-only-12-jobs-for-users-from-japan) In in that question there was a specific bug that was solved. I am not pointing to a specific location bug, I want to discuss if filtering searches by client IP has any practical use or not.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/252011/show-the-targeted-region-when-viewing-job-listings

Answer (score 4):

That's actually a setting on your job listing. We give customers the ability to target certain geographical zones. In your case the listing is probably set to target Europe, essentially "hiding" the listing from anyone we can determine is outside of that area.

If you have concerns, I would suggest changing the targeting to worldwide, that will fix your issue.

Many companies like this option because it allows them to avoid applicants from widely inappropriate locations when they are not advertising relocation or remote work.

Comment: Ok. Maybe it could be of use if you really want to hide your listing for some regions. But it can easily exist the case when someone is looking for a job while being outside the region in which they live in, or maybe someone that is about to move to that region. I think is misleading. If you don't people for some regions to apply, I think it would be enough with some tag or warning. You can even mark the application like sent from outside the region.